# WSO2: Identity Server

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I'm working on a POC using WSO2 IS(5.0.0) and WSO2 APIM(1.8.0). We also use ADFS for SSO.

In WSO2 IS,I've added ADFS as the IDp and have configured and have configured "SAML2 Web SSO Configuration". I'm using a sample application provided by Pushpalanka in her blog. When I access the [sample application](http://pushpalankajaya.blogspot.com/2014/09/leveraging-federation-capabilities-of.html), I get the following exception:

> TID[-1234] [IS] [2015-05-11 16:56:27,533] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil} - Error in bootstrapping the OpenSAML2 library org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.(XMLConfigurator.java:98) org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.(XMLConfigurator.java:73) org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.initializeXMLTooling(DefaultBootstrap.java:182) org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap(DefaultBootstrap.java:87) org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil.doBootstrap(SAMLSSOUtil.java:426) org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil.unmarshall(SAMLSSOUtil.java:231) org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.SAMLSSOService.validateSPInitSSORequest(SAMLSSOService.java:68) org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleSPInitSSO(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:259) org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleRequest(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:177) org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.doGet(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:91) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47) org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156) org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407) org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004) org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

My aim to implement the Delegated Access Control pattern. Any reference/samples will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure ADFS IDP as a federated authentication for your service provider. It can be configured from **Federated Authentication** option in **Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration** settings of your Service Provider application. Please refer to [this link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Adding+a+Service+Provider) for more information.